# How to cleanly spawn a process with arbitrary argument strings

Tags: c#

I'm looking to spawn a command with a given set of arguments, and these arguments can be arbitrary strings - particularly, a single argument can contain spaces, colons, etc.  I'd like to do this without having to escape the arguments string(s), mainly because I find that it almost inevitably leads to over, under, or mis-escaping at some point.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to do this with the `System.Diagnostics.Process` API - `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` always splits the string on whitespace and has some special interpretation for some other characters.  What I'm doing currently is spawning `xargs --null` (I'm developing on Linux) with the command to run and feeding it the arguments via stdin.  This works, but isn't going to win any awards for most beautiful solution.

Is there a better .NET API to use to do what I want?

**Edit:** For an example, consider wanting to pass the argument `“I am a filename with crazy characters "'%1!#\^*☺” fear my splitting`.  It's possible to escape that - *as far as I'm aware* all that needs to happen is to throw `"` around it and then escape the embedded `"` with `\`.  It's just that not having to escape it at all would be clearer, simpler, and less likely to get wrong.

Comment: If you end up mis-escaping *anything*, your code has at least one bug. Find it and fix it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do.  Fix mis-escaping by removing the *need* to escape.  My experience is that escaping is hard to get absolutely correct all the time, so I want to - *and can* - avoid it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that passing several arguments to a program is properly standardized in Windows. When you start a process, you can pass a command line to the executable. But how this command line is interpreted, is up to that program.

In theory, every program could use a different scheme for splitting the command line into single arguments and for escaping white space, quotes and special characters.

In practice, most programs will use the command line splitting that's part of VisualStudio C standard library. If you have the VisualStudio installed (incl. the C/C++ part), you'll find the command line parsing code in the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\stdargv.c`

If I understood the code correctly, the rules are pretty simple:

- Several arguments are separated by white space (space and tab characters)
- Arguments can be quoted with double quotes (they have to if they contain white space)
- If the arguments contain double quotes, the double quotes must be escaped with a back slash
- Backslashes have to double if and only if they are followed by a double quote.

For constructing a valid command line, these rule should be straight forward to implement. But as far as I know there is no Windows or C# function providing this functionality.

Comment: Ah.  The BCL lacking support for this makes more sense if Windows itself doesn't support it :).  fork/exec it is!